# Resolving ambiguous grammar without resorting to GLR-Parser

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I have a grammar that has two different possibilities when parsing `'if' expr 'then'`. There's a simple "assignment", such as `if foo then bar=1; else bar=0;`  then there's what I'm calling an "if_block" of code which can contain one or more "assignments":

```
if foo then
{
    bar = 1;
    if xyz then abc = -1;
}
else
{
    bar = 0;
    if xyz then
    {
       abc = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm handling nested if_blocks by way of the [dangling else](http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/~heckendo/CS445/danglingElse.html) matched/unmatched block.

My (**very** simplified) grammar is basically:

```
program : if_blocks
if_blocks : if_block | if_block if_blocks
if_block : assignments
assignments : assignment | assignment assignments
assignment : simple_assignment | if_assignment
```

So my predicament is with an assignment followed by an if_block. For example:

```
foo = bar;
if foo then
{
   foo = foo + 1;
}
```

`foo = bar;` is an assignment that, in this case, should be reduced to an if_block. `if foo then { ... }` is itself an if_block. Thus this whole code is if_block+if_block (reduced to if_blocks). But after `foo = bar;` is reduced to an assignment, there's not enough lookahead to know whether `if foo then` is another assignment (within the `foo = bar;` if_block) or if it's a separate if_block.

I've added `%glr-parser`, which seems to resolve this, but I run into other situations where multiple branches of the parsing survive and I can't seem to reconcile the different S/R branches. What's the accepted practice for this kind of situation, absent switching to a completely different scanner/parser (which would be a lot of work for me to learn and rewrite code) or changing the language (which I can't do)? Is there an easy resolution (somehow defining with `%dprec`?) using GLR or a tweak to the grammar?

Comment: %glr-parser shouldn't get rid of the problem; it should just rig it so the parser produces both parses.  You only want *one* parse.

Comment: Yes, but as I understand %glr-parser, any branches that fail to parse will silently die. If I'm left with only one successful parse, then no problem; however, if multiple parses succeed, I must define which branch I want to keep. I haven't figured out how I'm supposed to do that. (It appears maybe I need `%dprec` somehow?)

Answer (score 1):

Classically the dangling-else problem is solved by insisting that an **else** is attached to the nearest **if**, which (conceptually) resolves the ambiguity.  Somehow you need to communicate that idea to the parser generator to make the ambiguity really go away.

Most parser generators (including YACC and Bison) have some way of saying that when there is shift-vs-reduce conflict for a token, prefer the "shift", which can be used to acheives exactly this effect for the **else** keyword.    I don't know what the idiom is for YACC or Bison, but it should be easy to find in the grammar description information.

(I use my own GLR parser, and it is still useful to say this, because it gets rid of the ambiguous parse in an easy way).